# Browser does not replace an include file by its including file

Tags: javascript, methods

I am an absolute beginner in JS.

1) What I'm trying to do:

My web pages are composed of an index.php which is the same for all the files of a directory and one of a set of content.inc, like this: index.php?open=content.inc. This is done by a PHP snippet in the index.php and works well.
However, Google indexes all the content.inc files. The user's browser then displays the content.inc without the framing index.php. This I want to avoid. I therefore add a modest script at the beginning of each content.inc (which I would convert into a function once it runs) to tell the browser that instead of displaying the content.inc, it should display index.php?open=content.inc.

2) My unworkable solution:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
if (filename.indexOf("index.php") = -1)
    { var frame_name = "index.php?open="+filename;
        window.location.replace(frame_name);
     };
```

The browser (Firefox 60) ignores this; it displays content.inc. (I also have versions of this script which get the browser into an endless loop.)

What is wrong here? Please help!

PS: Please be assured that I have done extensive web search on this problem and found many pages of complaints about location.replace getting into an infinite loop; but none matches my situation. However, I gratefully accept a helpful link as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have an error in this line:

```
if (filename.indexOf("index.php") = -1)
```

That's an assignment and will always evaluate to `true`, you need to use `==` or `===` (which should be more performant).

Comment: I apologize for bothering you with a silly mistake. I might add that I had tried to use Mozilla's debugger on the console. However, since the version of the above code with the == error corrected gets into an infinite loop, I had to kill Firefox each time that I tried the script, with the effect that I never got to see the debugging report. Do you happen to know any way of countering this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The guilty line is on your test case (see JP de la Torre answer). And to improve, here's a snippet to demo how to analyze the url with a regular expression :

```js
function redirect(url) {
  if(url && url.indexOf('.inc') >= 0) {
    return url.replace(/\/(\w+)\.inc/, '/index.php?open=$1');
  }
  return url;
}

let urls = [
  window.location.href,
  'http://google.fr',
  'http://example.com/index.php?open=wazaa',
  'http://example.com/wazza.inc'
];

urls.forEach(url => {
  console.log(url, ' => ', redirect(url));
});
```

The regexp will capture any text between a / and .inc. You can use it then as replacement value with the $1.

And applied to your case, you simply need :

```
 if(window.location.href.indexOf('.inc') >= 0) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\/(\w+)\.inc/, '/index.php?open=$1');
  }
```

You can also use .htaccess server side to redirect request for .inc files on your index.php if mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: In principle, this is an elegant solution. However, it gets Firefox into an infinite loop. My diagnosis is the following:

If I understand the regex well, your replaced url appears to leave out the ".inc" part of the content.inc. This is fine with the php code in the index.php which fills the content.inc into a certain HTML block, since this code completes 'content' to 'content.inc' [it appears that you have seen it?]. However, for some mysterious reason the file thus constructed again fulfills the input condition of your replacement, so it is executed again.

Again, no idea what to do.

Comment: The script will detect any request with .inc in it and redirect to index.php. If it goes in infinite loop, it means that browser finds .inc string in url again and again. Do you have a test server or maybe post your index.php code ?

Comment: I have meanwhile found the source of the error: When I call content.inc from my local host, everything works fine. What I had done in the test phase, instead, was double clicking on the file content.inc. This calls Firefox directly, skipping the local server. Calling Firefox directly with index.php gets it into a loop (for whatever reason).

The original problem is, thus, solved; thank you. Just in case anybody else might be interested in the solution, I could post the relevant portions of the two files. However, they do not fit in this box; and I don't see an option of appending them here.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. If I eliminate my errors from my question and explain how **not** to run the test, then much of the ensuing conversation including your useful hints would become off the point.

Comment: You can either :
- Edit your question by appending an EDIT section and leaves the original text before - for instance :
EDIT --------------------------------------------
Problem was not only caused by script failure (thx JP de la Torre && Bertrand) but also by the way I was calling my inc file...
- Answer yourself to your question
In both cases, you can refer to another answer to give some credits.

you can also leave as is and accept one of the two answers or voting up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem of including an INC file called separately is the one proposed by Bertrand in his second code snippet above. It presupposes (correctly) that the inc extension is omitted in the replacement.

As I reported above, Firefox may get into an endless loop if it opens a PHP file directly, i.e. without involving the local host (with its php module).